# How to make a column readonly in Datatables Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Jeditable plugin for the Datatables to edit the cells in a table. However, I would like to make a column readonly. How can I do that?

I am using the below function right now which helps me in editing the columns but I would like make the first column as read only.Could you please help me in that ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('#example tbody td').editable(function(sValue) {
        /* Get the position of the current data from the node */
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);

        /* Get the data array for this row */
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);

        /* Update the data array and return the value */
        aData[aPos[1]] = sValue;
        return sValue;
    }, { "onblur": 'submit' }); /* Submit the form when bluring a field */
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

});
```

below is the table which I am using.
    
        
            
                Company name
                Address
                Town
            
        
        
                
                    Microsoft Hyderabad
                    Mindspace
                    Hyd
                
                
                    CTS chennai
                    Brilliant
                    Chennai
                
                
                    CSC Noida
                    DLF
                    Noida
                
                
                    INfy Bangalore
                    DLF Building
                    Bangalore

Comment: Can you include relevant code of your current situation?

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your reply.I am new to Stackoverflow. while I am trying to add the code I am getting some errors so could not upload

Comment: To mark code in the textarea just use identation of 4 and more space chars. Post only relevant portion of the source code.

Comment: thanks!
I have added the function which I am using Please let me know if you need any code further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: mark the fields in your table that should be not editable with `class="readonly"` and add it to your selector `$('#example tbody td:not(.readonly)')`.

Comment: Thanks a ton its working fine..
Is there any other way  such that we can make a column dynamically like passing the column number so that it will be more helpful

Comment: You could use a large number of selectors, eg. what you ask here is ``td:eq(2)``. Please refer to the jQuery documentation for further information: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/